# Install package dependencies with setup.py and wheels

Tags: python, pypi, python-wheel, devpi

We're using an internally hosted PyPI server (`devpi-server`) so that we can host binary wheels of huge packages that take a long time to install from source like scipy, matplotlib, etc. Installing these packages with `pip install scipy` works perfectly and definitely uses the wheel we've created. However, working with any of our internally developed python packages that have a dependency on one of these packages and running `python setup.py install|develop|test|whatever` results in the following error:

```
No local packages or download links found for scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 136, in <module>
    'develop': DevelopCommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/users/me/virtualenvs/devpi-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
  File "/users/me/virtualenvs/devpi-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_eggs
    parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg
  File "/users/me/virtualenvs/devpi-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 564, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
  File "/users/me/virtualenvs/devpi-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 802, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
  File "/users/me/virtualenvs/devpi-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 814, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/users/me/virtualenvs/devpi-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/users/me/virtualenvs/devpi-test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 587, in easy_install
    raise DistutilsError(msg)
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('scipy')
```

And with `easy_install`:

```
$ easy_install scipy
Searching for scipy
Reading http://pypi.internal.example.com/us/base/+simple/scipy/
No local packages or download links found for scipy
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('scipy')
```

If I grab the URL it's looking at I get:

```
$ curl http://pypi.internal.example.com/us/base/+simple/scipy/
<html>
  <head>
    <title>us/base: links for scipy</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>us/base: links for scipy</h1>

    <form action="http://pypi.internal.example.com/us/base/+simple/scipy/refresh" method="post"><input name="refresh" type="submit" value="Refresh PyPI links"/></form>
us/external <a href="../../../external/+f/c48/5006bc28a8607/scipy-0.14.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl#md5=c485006bc28a8607b2fc1331df452dc1">scipy-0.14.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</a><br/>
</body></html>
```

If I request the URL listed in that output, I get the wheel:

```
$ curl --silent 'http://pypi.internal.example.com/us/external/+f/c48/5006bc28a8607/scipy-0.14.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl#md5=c485006bc28a8607b2fc1331df452dc1' \
      | file -
/dev/stdin: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Comment: How do you pass the PyPI URL to pip?

Comment: By setting index_url in ~/.pip/pip.conf or passing -i INDEX_URL at the command line.

Comment: It looks like setuptools/distutils doesn't support installing wheels. Is this correct? It seems weird since they support creating wheels.

Comment: Distutils surely does not support that. Setuptools should though. Are you sure you are running the latest version?

Comment: Looks like from within the source directory, where `setup.py` is, you can do `pip install .` and it will work. Pip will use the `whl`s from our internal PyPI repo, but plain setuptools/distutils won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the issue described in the question does not depend on using `devpi` and can be reproduced with any PyPI server, including the main repo at [pypi.org](https://pypi.org). Example:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='spam', install_requires=['vprof>0.37'])
```

(Instead of `vprof`, you can take any other package that does not ship anything besides wheels)

Test it:

```
$ pip install --upgrade "setuptools<38.2.0"
...
Successfully installed setuptools-38.1.0

$ python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing spam.egg-info/PKG-INFO
...
Processing dependencies for spam==0.0.0
Searching for vprof>0.37
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/vprof/
No local packages or working download links found for vprof>0.37
error: Could not find suitable distribution for 
Requirement.parse('vprof>0.37')
```

Bang. Things get worse when you declare a binary-only package as a build dependency:

```
setup(name='spam', setup_requires=['vprof>0.37'])
```

Now all of the build and packaging commands will also fail, being unable to download build deps.

The issue solely depends on `setuptools` version used. [Since 26 Nov 2017 and version 38.2.0, `setuptools` supports fetching and installing wheel dependencies](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v38-2-0), so if you still experience this issue:

#### upgrade `setuptools`

Newer OS releases should already ship a recent version of `setuptools`. For example, Ubuntu 18.04 has `setuptools==39.0.1` by default ([link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python/python3-setuptools)). If you still have the old `setuptools` installed, most of the time it will be managed by the system package manager, so you shouldn't update it via `pip`. You can user-install an additional copy of `setuptools`

```
$ pip install --user --upgrade "setuptools>=38.2.0"
```

or use virtual environments for that matter.